# Configuring Jersey logs in Apache Karaf

Tags: jersey, osgi, apache-karaf

I am trying to configure Jersey to write its logs to my Karaf logs.
I have installed the Jersey related bundles to my karaf and also configured pom.xml for my REST bundle.
I have got the web service working , however i am unable to configure jersey to log to my Karaf log file.
Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: I have seen Karaf documentation and it says that is supports Java Util Logging which is what Jersey uses for logging. However i am not sure why i cannot see the logs even when try to set them via Karaf. The OPS4J Pax logging is what Karaf is using internally and it supports JUL as well.

JUL - extra handling without a pax-logging specific facade and shadowing. Only handler redirection
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(name).info("INFO using java.util.logging");